# Is there an error baseline feature for Typescript

Tags: typescript, psalm-php

The PHP linter "Psalm" has a feature called [baseline](https://psalm.dev/docs/running_psalm/dealing_with_code_issues/#using-a-baseline-file). It can be used to "ignore" errors that are tracked by a baseline file but prevent new errors from accumulating. This is useful in larger or legacy codebases where there are lots of errors that you can't fix right away but you still want to use linting to prevent new errors on incoming code changes.

Is there such a thing for typescript?

Comment: Unlikely. Typescript is a compiler, not a linter, so if it doesn't understand the code it won't be able to emit the compiled JS.

Comment: AFAIK that is not true. tsc should still compile if the errors are not too dramatic. This is especially true for errors like "you passed a variable of a wrong type to function xyz".